# Alpha channel not working for RGBA BITMAP

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

I need to display an 'Empty' Bitmap (all values zero for RGBA channels) in a dialog.

Rough code:

```
HWND img = ::GetDlgItem( hwnd_, 228 );
unsigned char* charFrame = new unsigned char[frame_height*frame_width*4];

HWND hImage = CreateWindow(L"STATIC", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_BITMAP,
    0, 0, frame_width, frame_height, img, (HMENU)1,GetWindowInstance( hwnd_ ),0);

HBITMAP bmp1 = CreateBitmap(frame_width,frame_height,1,32,charFrame);
SendMessage(hImage, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM) (HANDLE) bmp1);
DeleteObject((HBITMAP)bmp1);
```

In the above code, *charFrame* variable is an *unsigned char* * pointer which has all the values set to zero. *hwnd_* is the window handle.

Upon executing the code snippet, the window to which the BITMAP is sent, is not displaying the alpha content of the image. It displays a black image(R G B=0 0 0).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't `RGB = (0,0,0)` a black image? If you want a white image then you should have `RGB = (255,255,255)`

Comment: You asked for black, and got black. An alpha value of 0 means no translucency. Then again, we cannot see your actual code, so who knows what you've done. I urge you to put more effort into asking the questions. Show a [mcve].

Comment: Further to the above comments, be aware that the GDI functions are essentially rgb only - no a channel. While you can use TransparentBlt to copy an image with transparency to another bitmap, you can't for instance, draw text with transparency without resorting to GDI+ - the 'transparency' in GDI text rendering merely refers to the colour used for the background - you have to monkey-about with paths to achieve that.

Comment: @enhzflep is correct, though there are a couple GDI functions that will respect the alpha channel, most (including the ones you're using) do not.

Comment: @David Heffernan:  An alpha of 0 means completely transparent.  An alpha of 255 means completely opaque.  I think the fundamental problem is that the GDI functions being used don't respect the alpha channel.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the valuable comments. I have not been much into Win32 programming, which forced me to make such a question here. If I have to use GDI+, which is the best method to make use of alpha channel?

Comment: Since you are drawing alpha *images*, you can use the GDI `AlphaBlend()` function. It's a bit of work to set up, but you should be able to do it. For GDI+, it natively supports the alpha channel with no additional work (as far as I know).